# Azure C# function to call form recogniser cognitive services sample

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage, azure-form-recognizer

I used the form labelling tool to create a custom model and that was a pretty easy job.
For some time, I have been trying to create a simple azure C# function and would appreciate if someone could help with this.
My function should be very simple: a blob triggered function that would call the form recognizer cognitive service (with the modelID I already created using the labelling tool)and store the result in a cosmos DB or Table storage account.
I can share my code if that would be useful.

Thanks and best regards.

```
    [FunctionName("FormRecognizerExample")]
    public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAsync([BlobTrigger("forms1010/{name}", Connection = "conform")]Stream myBlob, string name, Uri uri, string blobTrigger, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
        try
        {
            IFormRecognizerClient formClient = new FormRecognizerClient(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(subscriptionKey))
            {
                Endpoint = formRecognizerEndpoint
            };
            List<string> blobsToAnalyze = new List<string>();
            foreach (string strBlob in blobsToAnalyze)
            {
                CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(strBlob);

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    // Load blob into a MemoryStream object
                    await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(ms);

                    // Send to Form Recognizer to analyze
                    AnalyzeResult results = await formClient.AnalyzeFormAsync(config, aiTrainModelId, ms, log);

                    searchResults = FormRecognizerExample.AnalyzeResults(config, tableClient, results, log);
                }
            }
        }
        }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you share which are the attempts (code) you did at creating the Function and which are the errors you are facing? Have you already gone through all the existing samples https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp

Comment: Yes, sure. I passed through that material. I created an Azure function to call computer vision service and store the results in table storage, but the form recognizer looks a bit more difficult .

Comment: Not familiar with the FormRecognizer, but you might want to follow the guidelines regarding creating clients inside Functions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections#static-clients

Comment: Thanks, Matias. Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the issue.